# Is there a way to expand Makefile macros to create a rule?

Tags: gnu-make

In this makefile example:

```
EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES:= a/A.txt a/b/B.txt a/b/c/C.txt

EXTERNAL_TXT_NAMES:= $(notdir $(EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES))

DEST_TXT_FILES:= $(addprefix txt/, $(EXTERNAL_TXT_NAMES))

.PHONY:all
all: $(DEST_TXT_FILES)

$(DEST_TXT_FILES):
    cp $< $@

txt/A.txt: a/A.txt
txt/B.txt: a/b/B.txt
txt/C.txt: a/b/c/C.txt
```

one can see that the last three lines are formulaic.

***Is there a way to rewrite this Makefile so that the fixed destination elements of the `DEST_TXT_FILES` can depend on the elements of the `EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES` from which they are derived without having to explicitly write them out?***

*For testing:*

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c txt && rm -f txt/* && touch a/A.txt a/b/B.txt a/b/c/C.txt && make
```

I was hoping that replacing the last three lines of the makefile with something like this would work:

```
foreach (FILE, $(EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES), $(addprefix txt/, $(notdir $(FILE))) : $(FILE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicated: [How can I use macros to generate multiple Makefile targets/rules inside foreach? Mysterious behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9691508/32836)

My solution:

```
EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES:= a/A.txt a/b/B.txt a/b/c/C.txt

EXTERNAL_TXT_NAMES:= $(notdir $(EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES))

DEST_TXT_FILES:= $(addprefix txt/, $(EXTERNAL_TXT_NAMES))

.PHONY:all
all: $(DEST_TXT_FILES)

define DUMMY_RULE
$(addprefix txt/, $(notdir $(1))): $(1)
endef

$(foreach FILE, $(EXTERNAL_TXT_FILES), $(eval $(call DUMMY_RULE, $(FILE))))

$(DEST_TXT_FILES):
    cp $< $@
```

Comment: If you want to learn more ways to do this check the series of blog posts here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/